# In Android programming,how to write the place holder in textview?

Tags: android, android-layout

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="TextView" />
```

i want to write place holder inside the textview....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add placeholder for textview. Placeholder for textview is meaningless .

You can add place holder for EditText using android:hint

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:hint="your placeholder text" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `android:hint`.

Example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Username" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Enter username" > // Code for placeholder
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

Output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use this from within your `xml` file

```
android:hint
```

or this from within  your `activity`

```
myText.setHint()
```

you can read more further by visiting this. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html